# Zip-file that contains nothing but itself?

Tags: compression, zip, quine

Just out of curiosity, does there exist a valid zip-file (according to format spec) that, contains nothing but itself?

Put another way, does the function implemented by `unzip` have a fix-point?

Can I write a program to search for such a fix-point in a intelligent (not-exhaustive) way?

I've thought about the opposite as well, i.e. if `zip` has a fix-point, but presumably a file can be compressed in different ways (different algorithms, different levels of compression and so on), thus whether or not `f = zip(f)` holds for some file `f` is probably implementation dependent. Since the zip-compression is loss-less however, the case for `unzip` should probably have a "formal" answer.

Has anyone explored this? Any pointers to related URLs are appreciated.

Comment: Hm...so you're looking for a binary file that, when "unzipped", yields itself?  Sort of like a [quine](http://bit.ly/1s2Gwe) of sorts?

Comment: There's also a gzip quine floating around on the web.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can read about it here: http://research.swtch.com/2010/03/zip-files-all-way-down.html

Here you will find [r.zip](http://swtch.com/r.zip), which contains itself.

Comment: Sent the file to a few friends.... "Here guys, a fun pic... it's a bitmap, so I zipped it a few times to get the size down." ;)