# how to unzip zip files with inner zip files recursively and still maintain the Same directory structure

Tags: linux, python-2.7, shell

Can anyone please help me to advise how to loop through a Zip file that contains child zip files (and even more sub folders in zipped format) and still maintain the folder structure after unzipping them? I want to attain this by **linux script or Python 2.7 (not Python 3)**

Basically, below is what I have:

ZIPPED File Structure

```
--CLASS1.zip

       --SUBJECT1.zip

       --SUBJECT2.zip

       --SUBJECT3.zip

       --SUBJECT4.zip



--CLASS2.zip

       --SUBJECT1.zip

       --SUBJECT2.zip

       --SUBJECT3.zip

       --SUBJECT4.zip



--CLASS3.zip

       --SUBJECT1.zip

       --SUBJECT2.zip

       --SUBJECT3.zip

       --SUBJECT4.zip
```

The level of zipping might go further but I gave just for illustration purpose. I want to maintain the same directory structure even after Unzipping like shown below:

--CLASS1

```
       --SUBJECT1

       --SUBJECT2

       --SUBJECT3

       --SUBJECT4



--CLASS2

       --SUBJECT1

       --SUBJECT2

       --SUBJECT3

       --SUBJECT4



--CLASS3

       --SUBJECT1

       --SUBJECT2

       --SUBJECT3

       --SUBJECT4
```

Please suggest the best possible way to attain this.

Comment: What should happen with a zip file containing itself? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169256/1030675

Comment: I'll check that later. You'll need to recursively go on folder you extract from your archive. Let say you extract CLASS1 folder, you'll want to list all zip under CLASS1.zip then do it again, until you don't find zip file anymore. That would be easier on python i think. 
You can try something but i can't help you right away :)

Comment: Also, you could check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files

Comment: In Python 3, I created the below snippet and its working but I want this to be done in Strict Python 2 and I don't know why I am unable to get that done :(

Comment: This is working Python 3 script, but need Python2:
`code`
import logging
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import unpack_archive
import shutil
import glob,os,re,sys
    zip_files = Path(unzip_dir).rglob("*.zip")
    while True:
        try:
            path = next(zip_files)
        except StopIteration:
            break # no more files
        except PermissionError:
            logging.exception("permission error")
        else:
            extract_dir = path.with_name(path.stem)
            unpack_archive(str(path), str(extract_dir), 'zip')
`code`

Comment: Alternatively, I am trying in Linux:
`code`
find . -iname '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -o -d "${0%.*}" "$0"' '{}' ';'
`code`

               However, running this only unzips on first level. But re-running the line again unzips all the inner zip files. This seems working but it doesn't looks good approach. Any other ideas please