# Digital signature for a file using openssl

Tags: cryptography, openssl, rsa

Is there a way to digitally sign a x509 certificate or any document using openssl?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, the [dgst](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html#) and [rsautl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html) component of OpenSSL can be used to compute a signature given an RSA key pair.

#### Signing:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 data.txt > hash
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey privatekey.pem -keyform PEM -in hash >signature
```

#### Verifying just the signature:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey publickey.pem -pubin -keyform PEM -in signature
```

*Update: Capturing Reto's comments from below because this is an important nuance.  Presumably if you are going to the trouble to verify, you want to know the signature was produced on the plaintext to which it is attached:*

This might sound obvious for some but: Be aware, `rsautl verify` just decrypts the file `signature`. The output of this call is guaranteed to be produced by the owner of the private key, but beside that nothing else is being checked. So to actually verify the consistency of `data.txt` you have to regenerate the digest and then compare it against the output of `openssl rsautl -verify`.

#### Verifying that the owner of the private key does vouch for `data.txt`:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify publickey.pem -signature signature data.txt
```

For this operation, *openssl* requires the public key, the signature, and the message.

Comment: This will leave a hex/ascii form of the hash in the file "hash", if you wanted a binary version of the hash to be signed, you need to use "-binary" on the openssl dgst command line.

Comment: My version of `openssl` also required `-pubin` for verify to work.

Comment: This might sound obvious for some but: Be aware, `rsault verify` just decrypts the file `signature`. The output of this call is guaranteed to be produced by the owner of the private key, but beside that nothing else is being checked. So to actually verify the consistency of `data.txt` you have to regenerate the digest and then compare it against the ouptut of `openssl rsautl -verify`.

Comment: When security tools give a syntactically correct answer while doing something counter-intuitive it tends to lead to systems that fail silently and bad outcomes.  I figured the comment from @reto needed more visibility so I copied it to the answer.

Comment: thanks @T.Rob I recommend to just use my solution and ignore this answer completely :) !

Comment: Unfortunately an artifact of Stack Overflow makes that somewhat unlikely to happen.  Since this answer is the accepted one, it'll continue to be more visible than yours.  I did at least vote yours up.

Comment: when I pass the publickey.pem to -verify option I get an error saying `unable to load private key, EXPECTING ANY PRIVATE KEY`. After passing private key again in -verify option I get the sha256 hash back which I signed with private key. After getting the sha256 hash I need again calculate the hash of orignal text and compare with sha256 output hash of -verify option.

Comment: @reto Yes you are right. The simple fix is to use `openssl dgst` to do the verification. This of course requires the plaintext to do its work. `openssl dgst -sha256 -verify publickey.pem -signature signature data.txt`

Comment: Hi, I just test with the same way. I use "openssl rsautl -verify -inkey publickey.pem -pubin -keyform PEM -in signature" to get the hash value, and it's the same as my hash file. But I use "openssl dgst -sha256 -verify publickey.pem -signature signature data.txt", it shows Verification Failure. Why is that happened?

Comment: @Neal I had the same problem I think the signature with rsautl is only done on the hash.
The openssl dgst man page has the correct example to do signing and verification https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-dgst.html

`openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privatekey.pem -out signature data.txt`

and to verify

`openssl dgst -sha256 -verify publickey.pem -signature signature data.txt`

Answer (score 97):

**To Generate Private Key**

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048
```

**To Sign**

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privatekey.pem -out data.txt.signature data.txt
```

**To Generate The Public Key**

`dgst -verify` requires the public key

```
openssl rsa -in privatekey.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out publickey.pem
```

**To Verify**

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify publickey.pem -signature data.txt.signature data.txt
```

- In case of success: prints `"Verified OK"`, return code `0`
- In case of failure: prints `"Verification Failure"`, return code `1`

Comment: This helped - I had the crt file, but didn't know how to go about verifying without the .pub file. Now I know ;-)

Comment: To clarify, `some-file.sha256` is actually the signature (e.g. signature.txt), and `some-file` is actually the message to be signed (e.g. message.txt). So in both operations, `some-file` is an input file. In the `-sign` operation, `signature.txt` is an output file, and in the `-verify` operation, `signature.txt` is an input file. I would edit it, but I'll let you do that if you wish.

Comment: @reto Is `some-file.sha256` is a binary file? is this normal? Since after doing so I got a content of a file that looks like this `@ugڻ��^{�{�9T�*�xAO"kd{�����d������͊��(����k�,A'c;�&�g��[b��e�i:��hh0���^���:�Y@��e�$��A������-�?�'�`

After executing the given command: `openssl dgst -sha256 -sign snakeoil.key -out some-file.sha256 some-file`

Comment: @Roel It is normal and expected.

Answer (score 9):

To **digitally sign** document in openssl it will work

For this first your certificate should be trusted
it would be look like this

```
-----BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDbjCCAlYCCQCOyunl25ProDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB5MQswCQYDVQQGEwJJ
...
-----END TRUSTED CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then use following command

```
smime -sign -signer certificate.pem -inkey private.key -in test.txt \
    -out test1.txt -from ashish -to singhal
```