# How to sign files trustedly with OpenSSL

Tags: pdf, openssl, certificate, x509

How can you sign files on the *command line* while using a trusted identity?

For emails you get a x509 certificate, signed by a CA – can you use the same to sign files?

Or would the CA need to sign your public key, and you'd use the corresponding private key to sign the file?

Right now I just found a way to [sign files with the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782826/digital-signature-for-a-file-using-openssl), but not a way to have the public key signed by a CA, nor a way to sign files using the cert.

Comment: You don't sign files with a certificate.  Only with the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the x509 certificate **is** the signed public key!

It's the recipients who need to use the certificate to verify your identity, and the public key to verify the signature.

What they need to do is extract the public key from the certificate to use it for verifying:

```
openssl x509 -in me.crt -pubkey -noout > me.pub
```

Comment: Yes, the X509 Certificate is a signed structure that contains a public key, identity information associated with that key, and extensions that indicate what the key can and can't be used for.  You mentioned in your editing comments that you know you can't sign with a public key, but your answer above indicates that is what you are trying to do.  You should not sign with a certificate, or a public key extracted from a certificate.  You should sign with a private key and verify it with the public key or certificate.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't focussed enough and wrote signing again /: In my case I actually needed to extract the private key from a pkcs12 file, that confused me a little.

Comment: OK.  I removed my downvote.  You should change "sign" to "verify" in your original question as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't ever want to sign with a public key, because that signature is then meaningless.  Many people have a public key.  Only one person (the signer) should have a private key.  If you did sign with a public key, anyone else having that public key could also create a signature that is equally as valid.  There would be no way to determine who actually signed it, which defeats the purpose of signatures.  Also, there would be no way to verify a signature signed with a public key because no one would have the private key.

You always sign with a private key and verify with a public key.

Your signature can be accompanied by an X509 Certificate.  If the certificate is signed by a trusted entity, then whoever has this certificate and trusts it, can also trust the signature that was generated by the private key corresponding to the public key that is in the certificate.

The link you gave in your question contains the openssl commands to verify a signature.  In addition to the `openssl dgst` and `openssl rsautl` methods to verify a signature, you can also use [openssl pkeyutl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkeyutl.html).

```
openssl pkeyutl -verify -in data -sigfile signature.bin -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

Public key (contained in Certificate) is used for verification purpose. Private key of the public key is used to sign the data.

Your public key is signed by CA. You can use your corresponding private key for that public key to sign a file. Verifier will use public key to verify the signature of the file.

Certificate is public key signed by a CA. if the CA is trusted, then certificate will be trusted.

Since, you are using certificate to sign a file, then its purpose must also be mentioned in the certificate. So, ensure that CA allows to sign the file by specifying this in purpose field of the certificate.

Comment: ```openssl rsautl -verify -inkey me.csr``` would do it, then?

Comment: And which field is the purpose field? _X509v3 Key Usage_?

Comment: and which value exactly would it need?

Comment: me.csr looks like a certificate signing request, not a public key.  You can extract the public key from a CSR and then use that to verify a signature.

Comment: Ups, of course I ment me.crt – but what's the command in the end?