# Sign a package .deb with Certificate .p12

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate

I packaged a java application under ubuntu in .deb I would like to sign it.
under windows I use signtool.exe to sign the
.exe with command : 
 `signtool.exe sign / f cert.p12 / p passwordcert app.exe` .
Is there a similar command to sign under linux?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using openssl.

Convert the [.p12 to a .pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144046/converting-pkcs12-certificate-into-pem-using-openssl#15144560) and then sign the file with [pkeyutl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/pkeyutl.html), like:

> openssl pkeyutl -sign -in file -inkey key.pem -out sig

[There are other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782826/digital-signature-for-a-file-using-openssl).

Comment: Thank you Gesferson, It Works!